# System.IndexOutOfRangeException on input block cipher using c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, indexoutofboundsexception, block-cipher

I try to do a binary input into a block cipher with 256 bit long, with its own pattern.

using input class

```
private string inputBinary(string binary_, string rule)
{
    var positionArray = rule.Split("\t\r\n, ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    char[]  result_ = new char[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < binary_.Length; i++)
    {
        int position = int.Parse(positionArray[i]);
        result_[position] = binary_[i];
    }
    return new string(result_);
}
```

with rule

```
input_plain[0] = "60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 16, 59, 75, 77, 80, 84, 89, 95, 102, 110, 119, 129, 140, 152, 165, 15, 45, 58, 76, 79, 83, 88, 94, 101, 109, 118, 128, 139, 151, 164, 14, 178, 44, 57, 78, 82, 87, 93, 100, 108, 117, 127, 138, 150, 163, 13, 177, 190, 43, 56, 81, 86, 92, 99, 107, 116, 126, 137, 149, 162, 12, 176, 189, 201, 42, 55, 85, 91, 98, 106, 115, 125, 136, 148, 161, 11, 175, 188, 200, 211, 41, 54, 90, 97, 105, 114, 124, 135, 147, 160, 10, 174, 187, 199, 210, 220, 40, 53, 96, 104, 113, 123, 134, 146, 159, 9, 173, 186, 198, 209, 219, 228, 39, 52, 103, 112, 122, 133, 145, 158, 8, 172, 185, 197, 208, 218, 227, 235, 38, 51, 111, 121, 132, 144, 157, 7, 171, 184, 196, 207, 217, 226, 234, 241, 37, 50, 120, 131, 143, 156, 6, 170, 183, 195, 206, 216, 225, 233, 240, 246, 36, 49, 130, 142, 155, 5, 169, 182, 194, 205, 215, 224, 232, 239, 245, 250, 35, 48, 141, 154, 4, 168, 181, 193, 204, 214, 223, 231, 238, 244, 249, 253, 34, 47, 153, 3, 167, 180, 192, 203, 213, 222, 230, 237, 243, 248, 252, 255, 33, 46, 2, 166, 179, 191, 202, 212, 221, 229, 236, 242, 247, 251, 254, 256, 32, 1, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31";
```

the result is a binary_[i] does not match the specified array, with a description `IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled`

Comment: You're trying to access an element in your array that is outside the range of available values. Make sure that `binary_.Length` and `positionArray` are at least 256 long.

Comment: Block ciphers are binary constructions. If you use string anywhere within the cipher itself you may be doing it wrong. I agree with @Nasreddine, if it isn't the rule, it's probably `binary_`. That's real simple to test though, right? I presume you are able to use a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `input_plain[0]` into your function as a rule then the entry in `input_plain[0]` that is `256` will cause the out of bounds exception.

As you can see from the code, the rule gets split into a new `positionArray` object whose entries are later parsed into integers and saved into the `position` variable of your loop. The position variable is then used to index `result_`. Since the position variable is not modified it uses `256` directly from the rules string. Since the `result_` character array only has 256 entries its last indexabled entry would be 255. Thus indexing 256 would result in the exception you're seeing.

If I had to hazard a guess I would say that this code originated from a language that uses an 1-based index for its arrays. It seems most likely since I don't see the number 0 in `input_plain[0]`. Perhaps simply changing `int position = int.Parse(positionArray[i]);` to `int position = int.Parse(positionArray[i]) - 1;` would solve your problem.

Comment: Well spotted, that 256 Dex.